# Python regex multicharacter match inside set

Tags: python, regex

I want to split some text by these delimiters: `","`, `";"`, `" y "` (whitespace is necessary)

It should also *ignore any delimiters within parentheses*

Here's what I've tried for the first two:

```
re.split('[,;]+(?![^(]*\))', text_spam)
```

`'foo, bar; baz spam y eggs guido'`
should split into `['foo', ' bar', ' baz spam', 'eggs guido']`

I can't figure out how to include a multicharacter string inside the set to get the last delimiter.

TIA

Comment: `r'(?:[,;]| y )+(?![^(]*\))'`? Did you try alternation?

Comment: Can you give an example of a line you want to split, and your desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may consider using a non-capturing group with an alternation operator `|` to introduce a multi-character string as an alternative to a character set, and set the `+` modifier to the group:

```
r'(?:[,;]| y )+(?![^(]*\))'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZVd8m/1)

You may further strip the items you get and omit any empty items using

```
import re
text = "foo, bar; baz spam y eggs guido (foo, bar; baz spam y eggs guido)"
results = re.split(r'(?:[,;]\s*| y )+(?![^(]*\))', text)
print( list(filter(None, [x.strip() for x in results])) )
# => ['foo', 'bar', 'baz spam', 'eggs guido (foo, bar; baz spam y eggs guido)']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fJ6QnH)